# How do i access a included layout in my code?

Tags: android

So I have included a layout in my xml file but I want to get that included layout in my code and then add to it.

You get `View`s using `findViewByID()`

But I don't think that can be used in this case. This is the part of my XML that I am referring

```
<include
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/progress_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/instructions_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Post your XML files and explain further. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Done. thanks for the advice. I was editing as you were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You get views using 'findViewByID'
>
> But i don't think that can be used in this case

Sure you can. Give your included layout an id

```
<include layout=@layout/someLayout
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    .../>
```

then retrieve it with that id

```
View myLayout = (View) findViewById(R.id.myId);
```

then you can use that reference to get sub views from `someLayout.xml`

```
Button btn = (Button) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn1)
```

assuming `someLayout.xml` has a `Button` with id of `btn1`

Comment: You were spot on the first time, I was just confused, thanks. Will accept in 5 minutes when i can.

Comment: Ok, glad that made sense. As [Squonk pointed out in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596694/how-do-i-access-a-included-layout-in-my-code/31596740#comment51145274_31596694) you should include any relevant code. I at first thought this is what you were talking about but after reading it a couple more times I could see how it may be taken differently. It may save you from some downvotes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can still add `id` to your included layout and get it with it's id. Or You can give ID to the parent element in that layout (inside it) and you can still call it with that `id` as well.

```
<include android:id=”@+id/news_title”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/title”/>
```